# Get reference of payment object

Tags: checkout, payment

I've added some code to generate token using card info filled in 2checkout payment method in my customecheckout_index_index handle. The code should generate the token and use it for order placement.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    if( typeof( document.getElementById('payment_form_twocheckout') ) !== 'undefined' ) {
        TCO.loadPubKey(TcoEnv);

        payment.save = payment.save.wrap(
            function(callOriginal) {
                if( payment.currentMethod === 'twocheckout') {
                    var form = new VarienForm('co-payment-form');
                    if(!form.validator.validate())  {
                        return; 
                    } else {
       /// remaining code to get args and generate token
```

But it is giving console error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: payment is not defined

If I try `Payment.prototype.save` instead of `payment.save`, again it says Payment is not defined.

Comment: so probalby the payment js is not included or object not created jet

Comment: @AntonS: yes, how I can create reference of payment here?

Comment: like to any other js object make sure the js file is included and initiate the object

Comment: Js file is added but non of the payment objects are working there like payment.currentMethod is also not working.

Comment: so initiate the payment object like it is done in default checkout